# Most efficient way to change the mean and standard deviation of each channel in an RGB image to custom values?

Tags: python, performance, numpy, image-processing

I have a dataset of 512x512 RGB images. I have two 1x3 arrays

```
mean_value  = [0.485,0.456,0.406]
std_value = [0.229,0.224,0.225]
```

Each element represents the desired mean and standard deviation of one RGB channel.
This is the formula used to compute the new image,1 subscript representing the original image and 2 subscript representing the desired mean and std.

[image]

So far my code contained a for loop to run through all the channels.

```
for i in range(3):
        norm_tmp = np.subtract(img[:,:,i],np.mean(img[:,:,i]))
        std_mult = np.divide(std_value[i],np.std(img[:,:,i]))
        img[:,:,i] = np.add(mean_value[i],np.multiply(norm_tmp,std_mult))
```

However, I would like to avoid this and possibly find a numpy implementation that does it without the for loop. I've seen some attempts that use openCV functions as well, so if there's an efficient function, I'd also be happy with that but so far I haven't been able to come to a satisfying solution yet.

Answer (score 1):

You can do with broadcasting:

```
# random data
np.random.seed(42)
img = np.random.rand(512,512,3)

norm_tmp = img - img.mean(axis=-1)[...,None]
std_mul = std_value / img.std(axis=-1)[...,None]
scaled_img = mean_value + norm_tmp * std_mul
```

Output (scale on left)

[image]